# Evil-leader: Leader key working in special buffers like *Message*, *Backtrace*, etc

Tags: key-bindings, evil

The leader key works most buffers and in other special buffers like *Help* but not in others. Is there a setting for having evil-leader work in all buffers? This is an example of my evil-leader configuration

```
(use-package evil-leader
    :ensure t
    :config
    (global-evil-leader-mode t)
    (evil-leader/set-leader "<SPC>")
    (evil-leader/set-key
        "bd" 'kill-this-buffer
        "fd" 'init-file
        "ff" 'find-file
        "fs" 'save-buffer
        "k" 'switch-to-buffer
        "xh" 'mark-whole-buffer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [general.el](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el) since `evil-leader` is not update since 2014.

Here is a minimal example that works in `*Message*` and `*Backtrace*`

```
(use-package general
  :ensure t
  :after evil
  :config
  (general-create-definer tyrant-def
    :states '(normal insert motion emacs)
    :keymaps 'override
    :prefix "SPC"
    :non-normal-prefix "M-SPC")
  (tyrant-def "" nil)

  (general-def universal-argument-map
    "SPC u" 'universal-argument-more)

  (tyrant-def
    "bd" 'kill-this-buffer
    "fd" 'init-file
    "ff" 'find-file
    "fs" 'save-buffer
    "k" 'switch-to-buffer
    "xh" 'mark-whole-buffer))
```

Comment: For more detail, you can refer to my [config](https://github.com/tshu-w/.emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/core-keybinds.el#L23)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Would you happen to know how `general` compares to `hydra`? When I search for general, it looks like hydra comes up as a similar alternative

Comment: `general` is a high-level abstraction of Emacs evil and native key bindings (which can interact with `which-key`), while `hydra` is more like [`transient`](https://github.com/magit/transient) (built in now), with which one can define one key page after another with various functions.

Comment: Gotcha and out of curiosity, what is the `(tyrant-def "" nil)` for?

Comment: maybe because of [this](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el#how-do-i-prevent-key-sequence-starts-with-non-prefix-key-errors), I don't really remember.

Comment: No worries, that was helpful, thank you!