# Prefix key in general package does not work with emacs start up page (fundamental mode)

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, evil, prefix-keys

I am trying to define key bindings with general.el following emacs from scratch. However, the leader-prefix key (SPC) does not seem to work from the Emacs start-up page (Fundamental mode). It works with scratch and messages buffer though. However, reloading the config again makes it work. It is very annoying since I can not immediately use customized key bindings from the Fundamental mode page.

Here is my config for general:

```lisp
(use-package general
    :config
    (general-define-key
     :states '(global normal insert visual motion emacs)
     :keymaps 'override
     :prefix "SPC"
     :non-normal-prefix "C-SPC"
     "" nil

     "SPC"  '(counsel-M-x :which-key "M-x")
     "."    '(find-file :which-key "find file")
     "r"    '(:ignore r :which-key "toggles")
     "r f"  '(counsel-recentf :which-key "recent files")
     "r r"  '((lambda () (interactive) (load-file "C:/Users/saske/.emacs.d/init.el")) :which-key "reload config")
     "r t"  '(counsel-load-theme :which-key "choose theme")
     "r c"  '((lambda () (interactive) (find-file "C:/Users/saske/.emacs.d/config.org")) :which-key "edit config")))
```

I have used `keymaps` instead of `states` as well. Can anyone please give me a fix here so that the prefix also works from the Emacs start-up page?

I have followed the answers from [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70587/evil-leader-leader-key-working-in-special-buffers-like-message-backtrace?rq=1) and a few other places (of which I am not able to find the references at the moment). But nothing worked.

I am very new to emacs. Maybe I have a wrong understanding of this.